# Unable To Permanently Increase The Position Property of My Custom Slider

Tags: javascript

I am designing a Slider component which keeps track of the current `position` of its contents so it can properly display the current slide. It seems like I'm hard stuck with a simple problem, the `position` remains the same. I don't get what is the problem, since the `position` is defined as a property of the class. So it's outside the function that increments the `position`. I am also using a lambda expression, which shouldn't have any problem with referencing the property.

```
updateControls(value) {
    let position = parseInt(this.position);

    if (value === "auto") {
        let content = undefined;
        let display = undefined;

        Array.from(this.children).forEach((child) => {
            if (child.className !== "left-control" &&
                child.className !== "right-control") {
                    content = child;
                    display = window.getComputedStyle(content)
                                    .getPropertyValue("display");
                }
        });

        if (display === "flex") {
            content.style.display = "inline-flex";
        }

        else {
            content.style.display = "inline-block";
        }

        this.style.display = "flex";
    }

    if (!this.prev) {
        this.prev = document.createElement("button");

        this.prev.id = "prev";
        this.prev.className = "left-control";
        this.prev.textContent = this.prev.id;

        this.prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
                console.log(position);
                this.position = (position).toString();
            }
        );
    }

    if (!this.next) {
        this.next = document.createElement("button");

        this.next.id = "next";
        this.next.className = "right-control";
        this.next.textContent = this.next.id;

        this.next.addEventListener("click", () => {
                console.log(position);
                this.position = (position + 1).toString();
            }
        );
    }

    if (position === 0) {
        if (document.querySelector(`#${this.prev.id}`)) {
            this.prev.remove();
        }

        if (document.querySelector(`#${this.next.id}`)) {
            this.next.remove();
        }

        this.appendChild(this.next);
    }

    if (position > 0 && position < (this.slides.size)) {
        if (document.querySelector(`#${this.prev.id}`)) {
            this.prev.remove();
        }

        if (document.querySelector(`#${this.next.id}`)) {
            this.next.remove();
        }

        this.appendChild(this.prev);
        this.appendChild(this.next);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can create a minimal repucable example?

Comment: That's the minimal portion of my code since that's the method that makes sense even on its own. The complete code is quite hard to read.

Comment: Without example css and html is quite hard for us to help you.

Comment: I get you. But can you tell me what to do since I figured out the main problem is the local variable <code>position</code>? It stays 0 which is the initial value of the <code>this.position</code>. For some reason, I tried replacing all instances of <code>position</code> with <code>parseInt(this.position)</code) and it worked. Still I'm curious why was that the case and I would prefer if my code won't be verbose.